# Bash command lines in "Django" views.py file during production stage

Tags: python, django, bash, apache2

I'm working on a project, where I'm using bash command lines in views.py to start a program (https://github.com/cleardusk/3DDFA), which creates files.

I use this ugly line:

`os.system('cd ../cleardusk/3DDFA\npython main.py -f ../../django_project/media/'+filen+'\ncd ../../django_project/')`

For clarity:

```
cd ../cleardusk/3DDFA
python main.py -f ../../django_project/media/'+filen
cd ../../django_project/
```

Where variable "filen" is my filename of an uploaded photo.

Everything was working fine, when it was in development stage, but since I transfered my project on a server, this no longer works. At first I thought, I was having problems with virtual environments or ownership of the files or even permissions, but that was not the case. The "cleardusk 3ddfa" probably isn't called, because it does not generate new files.

I have searched for an answer, but it seems, no one is using bash command lines in views.py. I have to use bash, since it's only way to run "cleardusk 3ddfa" and I have to run it in views.py since in my project client uploads a photo and filename is there, which I use to call this program.

Apache Error log is as follows.

[image]

Is there a problem with Apache configuration or what?

Comment: For Apache, `/` is the directory you defined as your DocumentRoot.  So if you have your files under `/var/www/`, your code must take that into account for the `cd`.

Comment: `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` is written in /etc/apache2/django_project.conf and my django project is in home folder. I tried to set DocumentRoot to my django_project directory, but this didnt help